# Show consequence using resolution

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can resolution show that $G$ (a formula in DNF) is a consequence of $H$ (a finite *set* of formulas in CNF)?

I know that for $G$ to be a consequence of $H =\{F_1,F_2,...,F_n\}$, $(F_1\land F_2\land (...)\land F_n) \land \lnot G$ must be unsatisfiable.

But how can I prove that?

Comment: Apply [Resolution procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) to $H \land \lnot G$; if you reach the *empty clause* you have showed its unsatisfiability, that means: $H \vDash G$.

Comment: As you must know, all formulas must be in CNF.

Comment: See also [Conversion into CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Conversion_into_CNF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the clause set $\{ F_1,F_2,... F_n,\lnot G \}$

If you can derive the empty clause, then that show that this clause set is not satisfiable, i.e not all statements in the clause set can be true at the same time. Which means that if all the statements in $H$ are true, $\neg G$ cannot be true as well, and so must be false. But if $\neg G$ is false, then $G$ is true. In sum: if all the statements in $H$ are true, $G$ must be true as well, meaning that $G$ is a consequence of $H$.